# How to determine version of a golang module through its source code?

Tags: go, go-modules

Recently, I am trying to determine the version of a golang module. Usually, I will download a module's source code knowing the version of main module. But sometimes there are few submodules in other directories. Like [github.com/hashicorp/consul](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul), it contains two submodules as hashicorp/consul/sdk and hashicorp/consul/api. However when I download github.com/hashicorp/consul (version: v1.9.1), it's very difficult to determine the version of consul/sdk and consul/api because go.mod file doesn't contain any version information about this module. So, my question is how to get version of submodule in a golang module?
I read the [checksum documents](https://blog.golang.org/module-mirror-launch) and [endpoints documents](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/25530-sumdb.md#checksum-database). I wonder if I can compute a checksum of source files and compare it with versions' checksum in golang database to determine the version. As I read the endpoints api, I think this way is a little complex.
Another thought is to determine the version through git tag history. However, I don't think it's an accurate way.

Comment: You go.mod contains the version.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the `go.mod` file of github.com/hashicorp/consul you can see the versions:

```
    github.com/hashicorp/consul/api v1.8.0
    github.com/hashicorp/consul/sdk v0.7.0
```

(See e.g. https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/go.mod#L31)

Depending on what version you are using, check the respective `go.mod` file of that version.

As @Volker said, your `go.mod` file will probably also have the versions. If not your `go.sum` file will as it contains the checksums of all dependencies.

Comment: This could be a solution. However, if you switch the tag of this repo to [api/v1.8.1](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/tree/api/v1.8.1), you will find that the version of "github.com/hashicorp/consul/sdk" in [go.mod](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/api/v1.8.1/go.mod) is still v1.8.0 rather than v1.8.1. This indicates the method is not accurate.

Comment: Of course you can upgrade to a newer version of the sdk manually in your repo, instead of using the one that the consul team intended for that version of consul. But the OP wanted to know what version of the sdk belongs to consul v1.9.1. This answers that.

Answer (score 0):

To determine all version of dependencies try to use `go list` tool ([List packages or modules](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages_or_modules))

For example (list of all dependencies with versions)

```
% cat go.mod
```

```
module github.com/hashicorp/consul

go 1.13

replace github.com/hashicorp/consul/api => ./api  replace ➡️ consul/api v1.8.0

replace github.com/hashicorp/consul/sdk => ./sdk  replace ➡️ consul/sdk v0.7.0

replace launchpad.net/gocheck => github.com/go-check/check v0.0.0-20140225173054-eb6ee6f84d0a

require (
    github.com/Microsoft/go-winio v0.4.3 // indirect
    github.com/NYTimes/gziphandler v1.0.1
    github.com/armon/circbuf v0.0.0-20150827004946-bbbad097214e
    github.com/armon/go-metrics v0.3.6
    github.com/armon/go-radix v1.0.0
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.25.41
    github.com/coredns/coredns v1.1.2
    github.com/coreos/go-oidc v2.1.0+incompatible
    github.com/digitalocean/godo v1.10.0 // indirect
    github.com/docker/go-connections v0.3.0
    github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs v0.0.0-20160803192304-e1a2a7ec64b0
    github.com/envoyproxy/go-control-plane v0.9.5
    github.com/frankban/quicktest v1.11.0 // indirect
    github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.2.2-0.20190723190241-65acae22fc9d
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.5
    github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.2
    github.com/google/go-querystring v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/google/gofuzz v1.2.0
    github.com/google/tcpproxy v0.0.0-20180808230851-dfa16c61dad2
    github.com/hashicorp/consul/api v1.8.0  replace
    github.com/hashicorp/consul/sdk v0.7.0  replace
...
```

```
% go list -json -m -u all
```

```
{
        "Path": "github.com/hashicorp/consul",
        "Main": true,
        "Dir": "/Users/a18388871/GoProjects/consul",
        "GoMod": "/Users/a18388871/GoProjects/consul/go.mod",
        "GoVersion": "1.13"
}

...

{
        "Path": "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway",
        "Version": "v1.9.0",
        "Time": "2019-05-14T09:07:28Z",
        "Update": {
                "Path": "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway",
                "Version": "v1.16.0",
                "Time": "2020-10-28T10:29:51Z"
        },
        "Indirect": true,
        "Dir": "/Users/a18388871/go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway@v1.9.0",
        "GoMod": "/Users/a18388871/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/@v/v1.9.0.mod"
}
{
        "Path": "github.com/hashicorp/consul/api",
        "Version": "v1.8.0",
        "Replace": { . Replace field describes the replacement module, and its Dir field is set to the replacement's source code
                "Path": "./api",
                "Dir": "/Users/a18388871/GoProjects/consul/api",
                "GoMod": "/Users/a18388871/GoProjects/consul/api/go.mod",
                "GoVersion": "1.12"
        },
        "Update": { ' The -u flag adds information about available upgrades'
                "Path": "github.com/hashicorp/consul/api",
                "Version": "v1.8.1",
                "Time": "2020-12-10T20:49:49Z"
        },
        "Dir": "/Users/a18388871/GoProjects/consul/api",
        "GoMod": "/Users/a18388871/GoProjects/consul/api/go.mod",
        "GoVersion": "1.12"
}


...
```

Comment: This may not be very accurate because the most recent version of consul/api is [v1.8.1](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/tree/api/v1.8.1). While when using the command in the directory, I still get v1.8.0. What's more, sometimes the main module doesn't use submodule as its dependency. Like, [github.com/google/cadvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) and its submodule [github.com/google/cadvisor/cmd](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/tree/master/cmd).

Comment: It happens because in `go.mod` uses `replace github.com/hashicorp/consul/api => ./api ` directive. `Replace` field in the output shows that dependency was replaced (in this case, from local project package of v1.8.1 version),  but еру `Version` field still shows version from `require` block of `go.mod`